# Save Data before starting a conversation

Tags: node.js, botframework

first time asking a question here, so sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

Well, I want to save a variable (session.userData.example) before starting a conversation, therefore have it stored before the user writes anything. How can I do it?

Edit: SDK3

Comment: Please provide a code example and take a look at the recommendations for how to write a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It sounds like you want to have some information stored in userData as a sort of default starting point before any data is added to it as a result of interacting with the user. But before a conversation starts, there is no user and therefore no userData. Is it possible that you meant dialog instead of conversation? And can you explain more of your use case in terms of what you're trying to accomplish and why you want userData to be prestocked? Surely default values can be provided as soon as userData is accessed for the first time and found to be empty.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Hey @KyleDelaney I can't provide any code examples, but what I want is some default values ready as soon as I start my conversation

Comment: Why can't you provide a code example? Just show what you're trying to do with `userData`

Comment: @KyleDelaney can t provide any code example because this is for a company, so I can't disclose code. As I said before, I need some variables to start with a value as soon as my conversation starts, I probably know a solution already, just didn t ve the time to implement it yet

Comment: You don't need to disclose your company's code. Just recreate the behavior in your own small sample

Comment: Are you still working on this?